# Generating keyPressEvent in a code generated by pyQT Designer

Tags: python, pyqt

I Created a code using pyQt Designer in ui and changed it to py code.

Now i want to add some Keypress events to my this  i.e. say if i click on keyboard key with numeric 3 , my label should have text 3 on it or it just print "Hi"

I have already checked a lot of forums over internet and found that its best to reimplement keyPressEvent to use keyboard events .  I tried that however somehow i am not able to make it work in the code generated by pyQT designer .

Below is the code generated by pyQT designer . I have put the code of keyPressEvent re implementation in it as well , however it dosent work :

```
try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):


        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)

        MainWindow.setFocus()

        def keyPressEvent(self, qKeyEvent):
            print "hi"
            print(qKeyEvent.key())
            if qKeyEvent.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
                print('Enter pressed')
            else:
                super(Ui_MainWindow).keyPressEvent(qKeyEvent)

        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 721, 80))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayoutWidget"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setMargin(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 110, 81, 41))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))

        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 260, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.textEdit.setText("I am a label")
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am new to this forum , it will be helpful if someone can help . I know this can be achieved by creating another class who inherits QMainWindow but i want to do this in the same code i.e in the code block generated by pyQT Designer .

Also please suggest If there is any way to do this without reimplementing keypressEvent

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are two reasons why your code doesn't work.

The first is that you are defining `keyPressEvent` inside the `setupUi` method, hence it is completely invisible to the class.

Secondly because in the code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You are creating an instance of `QMainWindow`, which uses its own implementation of `keyPressEvent`. You should create a subclass of `QMainWindow` and reimplement the method there.

---

## How to properly do this.

- Open the designer and create your mainwindow.
  [image]
- compile the `.ui` file using `pyuic`:

  ```
  $pyuic4 mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.py
  ```
- Create a **new** file where you'll write the subclass of the `QMainWindow`, `mymainwindow.py`. **Do no modify `ui_mainwindow.py`**. There is a big warning at the start of the file:

  > # WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

  If you don't want to lose all your code when changing the UI then do *not* modify the file.
- Implement the `keyPressEvent` in the subclass:

---

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

# import the UI from the generated file
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow


# it's not stricly necessary to subclass Ui_MainWindow.
class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # if you didn't subclass Ui_MainWindow simply do:
        # Ui_MainWindow().setupUi(self)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        # implement the method here
        self.label.setText(self.label.text() + 'a')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = MyMainWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

- Finally run the code and note that every time you press a key an `a` is added to the text.

Comment: No , i tried putting the keyPressEvent outside the other method as well , but no effect .

Comment: I did try exactly your code but it still not work, but only show empty new line if press enter, please tell me how i really need it

Comment: @coder5 I have followed the steps described in the answer and I see the expected output: everytime you press a key on the keyboard with the focus on the window an `a` is appended to the text. If you have a problem you should first check to see that you did *exactly* what described, and eventually you should ask a new question.